# Adobe analytics prevent click on link

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I'm working on a website where I need to implement Adobe Analytics. This is working, but for an unknown reason, some of my links are not accessible the usual way with adobe analytics enabled (they are when I remove Adobe Analytics script and references).

I need to double click on the link to access content, where I usually only need a single click to access content. Also, when I first clic on element, it trigger a network call to adobe analytics. The second clic trigger the clic of the element.

You'll find below snippets of working link, and not working links. They are quite similar, and I can't find why the behaviour is different.

I'm using jquery to manage my events, here is a sample :

```
(function ($) {

  var userId = $("head").data("user-id");
  if (userId === undefined || userId === "") {
    userId = "none";
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    digitaldata = {
      site: {
        platform: window.navigator.platform,
        language: window.navigator.language,
        environnement: ""
      },
      page: {
        pagename: document.title,
        primarycategory: "",
        subcategory: "" 
      },
      user: {
        userid: userId,
        connectionstatus: "" 
      },
      clic: {
        name: "",
        type: "",
        category: ""
      }
    };

    $(".participation").on("click", function () {
      var name = $(this).data("id");
      digitaldata = {
        'clic.name': name,
        'clic.type': 'liens_internes',
        'clic.category': 'promo_interne'
      };
      _satellite.track('clic_je_participe');
    });

    $('.advantage').on('click', function () {
      var title = $(this).data("title");
      digitaldata = {
        'clic.name': title,
        'clic.type': 'liens_internes',
        'clic.category': 'promo_interne'
      };
      _satellite.track('clic_profiter_avantage');
    });

    _satellite.pageBottom();
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Working links (only 1 click is needed to access content)

```
<nav class="menu-inner">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="link-account">
      <a href="/site">
        <span class="icon-arrow-left"></span>Mon compte
      </a>
    </li>
    </li>
          <li>
      <a href="https://store.site.com/" target="_blank">
          Store
        <span class="icon-chevron-right-slim"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Non-Working links (2 clicks to trigger link)

```
<div id="wrapper-inner-subnav" class="menu-inner-subnav-wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
        <ul class="z-1 list-unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/site/souscriptions" target="" class="active">
                    <span></span>
                    Souscriptions
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/site/avantages" target="" class="">
                    <span></span>
                    avantages
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/site/game" target="" class="">
                    Game
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have you any idea of this strange behaviour ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

At face value, either you have not posted enough context, or else I do not think Adobe Analytics (AA) tracking is the issue. Your css selectors for your click event listeners do not match anything in either of your posted html code snippets, so your click event callbacks won't trigger on click of anything in them.

So, either you have not posted enough context (maybe your css selector matches something higher up the DOM / xpath chain), or else your problem lies elsewhere.

But even supposing they do trigger, you will still need to provide some context about how the Direct Call Rules (DCR) you are calling are setup. DTM does not offer anything for stopping propagation/bubbling from a DCR, but you may have some custom code within it that is doing it.

On a sidenote, I noticed you have _satellite.pageBottom() buried inside a document.ready callback.  You should not do this. It will cause problems with 
 and in general limit DTM functionality (almost certainly not related to this, though).

The DTM Footer code should be placed directly on the page without being wrapped in anything.  And ideally it should be the only thing in a script tag block, to prevent failure of other code within the same script block from potentially causing the DTM Footer script from executing (or visa versa). IOW you should be this, all by itself (you may wrap it in a try..catch if you want).

```
<script>
_satellite.pageBottom();
</script>
```

And incidentally, Adobe will not support your implementation if you do not do it this way, if that's a thing you care about (you should, since Adobe Analytics costs a lot of money!)

Obviously this impacts your initial `digitalData` object availability, so you'll have to move that, too.

Comment: Theses links are just example, that shouldn't even be tracked by DTM. I've just posted theses as example, because when I removed my script and the adobe script, everything works fine. When I put it make (without any others change), the links given in example start to act in a weird way.

Comment: About your comment on the satellite object, I thought it would work the same and would allow me to get all my Adobe analytics in one place instead of getting it everywhere in my project. I'll try this and see if it help

Comment: "you will still need to provide some context about how the Direct Call Rules (DCR) you are calling are setup. DTM does not offer anything for stopping propagation/bubbling from a DCR, but you may have some custom code within it that is doing it."
Can you give me more details ? It's the first time I'm working with Adobe Analytics, and I've not been given/found much clear documentation except a Word document with some event to track. So I've got to declare my  DCR as I did, but what about the context ? Isn't it done by the digitalData object ?

Comment: I mean that you need to login to DTM and go to the Direct Call Rule and post details about what all is in there

Comment: I've been trying to test it again. I've put the `_sattelite.pageBottom()` in the bottom of my body tag. I've disabled my script so that no DTM tags are triggered. But I'm still having the same issue. If I disable the adobe analytics script, everything seems to be ok.

Comment: @Sylvain at this point there's really nothing else I can say due to lack of information. If you want me (or anybody, really) to be able to help you, then I suggest you provide a link to the page with the issue.